# different results for the same script when I am running script inside the for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which I am filter indivisual column I just created filter script for first column V1 it ran well. but using the same approach created for loop getting empty dataframes anyone suggest why is it so please help me Thank you

```
m1 <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
m1 <- as.data.frame(m1)


data1=m1[m1$V1 > 0, ]
data1=data1['V1']


for (i in colnames(m1)){
  m1_filter=m1[m1$i > 0, ]
  m1_filter=m1_filter[i]
  print(m1_filter)
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result of the loop?

Comment: @Skaqqs I need each column with non-zero values

Comment: `lapply(m1, function(x) x[x > 0])`